# Export RBAC from all the resource groups in Azure AD to one CSV

Tags: azure, powershell, rbac

I have dozen of RG's and its very difficult to output all role assignments from all resources from all resource groups at once. Can you please help me with Powershell script?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the PowerShell script you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Export RBAC from all the resource groups in Azure AD to one CSV

Here is the `PowerShell script` to output all **RBAC** role assignments from all `resource groups` in   `subscription`.

```
    Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "Subscription-Name"
    
    $roleAssignmentData = @()
    
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup
    
    foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
        $resourceGroupName = $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
        
        # Get all role assignments for the current resource group
        $roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
        
        # Iterate through each role assignment
        foreach ($roleAssignment in $roleAssignments) {
            $roleAssignmentData += [PSCustomObject]@{
                "ResourceGroupName" = $resourceGroupName
                "PrincipalName" = $roleAssignment.DisplayName
                "RoleName" = $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionName
            }
        } 
    }
    
    $roleAssignmentData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\ResourceGroups-Roles-Subscription.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output**

[image]

After running the above script, all `RBAC` role assignment from all `resource groups` in   `subscription` are successfully exported to an `Excel` file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Venkat, it's working perfectly fine